# Initialize unique_ptr with initializer_list in C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11

I am currently exploring the new c++11 features, I am wondering how to initialize the memory pointed by the unique_ptr, with the value I provided in the initializer_list. With a raw memory pointer like "T* data", I can use uninitialized_copy, but when I change from "T* data" to "unique_ptr data" (so I don't have to do explicit deconstruction) it does not work. I am still reading materials on unique_ptr (and my guess is that's because unique_ptr is not copyable), but could someone point out the function that does the job? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Vector
{
    private:
        unique_ptr<T []> data;
        int size;
    public:
        Vector(initializer_list<T> l)
        {
            size = l.size();
            cout << "Constructing, size is: " << size << endl;
            data.reset(new T[size]); // reserve memory
            uninitialized_copy(l.begin(),l.end(),data); // not working

            //for(int i = 0; i<size; i++ ) // not working -> l has no operator[]
            //    data[i] = l[i];
        }
        void Report()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i<size; i++ )
                cout << data[i] << ' ';
            cout << '\n';
        }
};
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int a = 1;
    Vector<int> v {1,2,3,4};
    v.Report();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use `copy`, not `uninitialized_copy`.  Otherwise, you're constructing it twice.  Once in `new T[size]` and then as part of `uninitialized copy`.  If you use `copy`, it will use assignment, and won't get you into trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the [getter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) :

```
std::copy(l.begin(),l.end(),data.get());
```

Comment: Tested, succeeded, happy :-)

Comment: Just one small question, where can I learn this? I googled but couldn't find something helpful (or I missed it), could you please recommend some material? Thanks!

Comment: i edit and put a link to the API, cppreference.com is a really great source of information.

Comment: Since `new T[size]` already default-constructed the objects, the `uninitialized_copy` means those will not be destructed, and any resources acquired by the default constructor of `T` will be leaked. Just use `std::copy`.